# How to sort the indices of Slice<UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Double>> using vDSP?

Tags: swift, sorting, vdsp

I’m using `buffer` in many other vDSP operations before the code below. To those operations it is naturally a contiguous piece of memory, and that’s handy as there are vastly reduced number of calls to vDSP.

```swift
// […] many operations with buffer here


var buffer = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Double>.allocate(capacity: 10000000)

var sortedIndices: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt> = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt>.allocate(capacity: 10000000)

for (indexIndices, indexC) in buffer.indices.enumerated() {
    sortedIndices[indexIndices] = UInt(indexC)
}

vDSP_vsortiD(
    UnsafePointer<Double>(buffer.baseAddress)!, 
    sortedIndices, 
    nil, 
    UInt(buffer.count), 
    vDSP.SortOrder.descending.rawValue
)
```

I need to sort `buffer` sliced up. Also, I’d like not to copy its contents before every sort into smaller buffers as this is performance critical (as many times as possible per second).

`vDSP_vsortiD()` and `vDSP_vsorti()` do not support `Slice`.

For example this code is not possible since `.baseAddress` doesn’t exist on a `Slice` and I guess `UnsafePointer` doesn’t understand `Slice` either.

```
var sliceOfBuffer: Slice<UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Double>> = buffer[0...30000]

vDSP_vsortiD(
    UnsafePointer<Double>(sliceOfBuffer.baseAddress)!, // This fails
    sortedIndices[0...30000], // This also fails
    nil, 
    UInt(30000), 
    vDSP.SortOrder.descending.rawValue
)

// Is there another sort indices function which accepts those types as params?
```

Many operations under `vDSP` accept `Slice`, however the above sort functions don’t.

Swift v5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `withUnsafeBufferPointer()` to pass the address of the slice's element storage to the vDSP function:

```
sliceOfBuffer.withUnsafeBufferPointer { bp in
    vDSP_vsortiD(
        bp.baseAddress!,
        sortedIndices,
        nil,
        UInt(sliceOfBuffer.count),
        vDSP.SortOrder.descending.rawValue
    )
}
```

With respect to slicing the indices: It *seems* that one can pass `sortedIndices + sliceOfBuffer.startIndex` to the vDSP function. However, the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1450736-vdsp_vsorti) states that the indices must be initialized starting at zero, so I would not rely on that.

Answer (score 1):

Given that it's a C API, it's less error prone to just think a little more in C terms.  Forget slices, just use pointers.

In C it would look something like this:

```
    double *buffer = (double *)calloc(size(double), 10000000);
    vDSP_Length *sortedIndices = (vDSP_Length*) calloc(size(vDSP_Length), 10000000);

    vDSP_vsortiD(
        buffer,
        sortedIndices,
        NULL,
        (vDSP_Length)30000,
        vDSP_SortOrder_descending // Probably a different name in reality
    );
```

And for sorting in the middle of the buffer it would look like this:

```
    const vDSP_Length sortOffset = 4000;
    const vDSP_Length sortCount  = 10000;

    vDSP_vsortiD(
        buffer + sortOffset,
        sortedIndices + sortOffset,
        NULL,
        sortCount,
        vDSP_SortOrder_descending // Probably a different name in reality
    );
```

In Swift the spelling of how you do that is a little different, but you do exactly the same thing.  You have an `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer`, so you're on the right track that you need to use its `baseAddress`, but you don't need to do anything else to it.  `UnsafeMutablePointer` types can be passed to `UnsafePointer` parameters for C calls (but not the other way around).  `sortedIndices` is already a pointer rather than a buffer pointer, so you can just use it directly.

```swift
    vDSP_vsortiD(
        buffer.baseAddress!,
        sortedIndices,
        nil,
        vDSP_Length(30000),
        vDSP.SortOrder.descending.rawValue
    )
```

If instead, you want to sort somewhere in the middle of your buffer:

```swift
    // index range of 4000..<14_000
    let startOfSlice = 4000
    let lengthOfSlice = 10_000

    vDSP_vsortiD(
        buffer.baseAddress!.advanced(by: startOfSlice),
        sortedIndices.advanced(by: startOfSlice),
        nil,
        vDSP_Length(lengthOfSlice),
        vDSP.SortOrder.descending.rawValue
    )
```

Comment: This doesn’t work, the sortedIndices does not contain the expected values. It is possible I may have done something wrong when reading the indices (tried reading both sortedIndices[0] and at the startOfSlice offset just in case…)

Sorting does run but I think the values in the buffer have become uncorrelated with the indices.

Comment: Maybe I was misunderstanding the problem.  Did initializing the sortedIndices (per Martin R's answer) fix the problem for you?

Comment: I’ve always run with the indices initialized (see my edited post), so no. Martin’s answer works though, same indices initialized in the same way

Comment: As for the way you read the indices, you'd read at whatever offset you advanced the pointer by, or 0 if you didn't advance, so it sounds like that wasn't the problem.  Also you don't really need to offset the pointers by the same amount.  If you want to always have the sorted indices at the start of `sortedIndices` you could just always pass that regardless of the offset into `buffer` you use.  But I think initializing indices is key, and makes sense, since `vDSP_vsortiD` will have to use them to do its sort.

Comment: I read your update.  You are right that `UnsafePointer` doesn't do slices.  Unlike with the buffer pointers,  often forget that the basic pointer types even have a subscript operator.   When I use pointers, I advance to where I want to look at use `ptr.pointee`, which my profiling shows is faster than indexing through buffers (protocol witness table thunking overhead shows up in the profiler).  Anyway, if Martin's answer works, I'm glad you have a solution.

Comment: It appears Swift does something magical behind the scenes to allow subsequent sorts by reusing the already sorted indices array without having to reinitialize. Rebasing buffers doesn’t work and results in uncorrelated sorts. Slices and .withUnsafeBufferPointer seem to be the only way.

Comment: Likely it's `vDSP_vsortiD` that does the "magic" rather than Swift.  Presumably it's using the indices to index into buffer to obtain values to compare, so if they're already sorted (or relatively sorted), it probably allows the sort to complete faster.   It's good to know that you don't need to reinitialize them.